# Concurrent program compiled with clang runs fine, but hangs with gcc

Tags: c++, multithreading, compilation, mutex, condition-variable

I wrote a class to share a limited number of resources (for instance network interfaces) between a larger number of threads. The resources are pooled and, if not in use, they are borrowed out to the requesting thread, which otherwise waits on a `condition_variable`.
Nothing really exotic: apart for the fancy `scoped_lock` which requires c++17, it should be good old c++11.

Both gcc10.2 and clang11 compile the test main fine, but while the latter produces an executable which does pretty much what expected, the former hangs without consuming CPU (deadlock?).

With the help of https://godbolt.org/ I tried older versions of gcc and also icc (passing options `-O3 -std=c++17 -pthread`), all reproducing the bad result, while even there clang confirms the proper behavior.

I wonder if I made a mistake or if the code triggers some compiler misbehavior and in case how to work around that.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>

template <typename T>
class Pool {
///////////////////////////
  class Borrowed {
    friend class Pool<T>;
    Pool<T>& pool;
    const size_t id;
    T * val;

    public:
    Borrowed(Pool & p, size_t i, T& v): pool(p), id(i), val(&v) {}
    ~Borrowed() { release(); }
  
    T& get() const {
      if (!val) throw std::runtime_error("Borrowed::get() this resource was collected back by the pool");
      return *val;
    }

    void release() { pool.collect(*this); }
  };
///////////////////////////    
  struct Resource {
    T val;
    bool available = true;
    Resource(T v): val(std::move(v)) {}
  };
///////////////////////////

  std::vector<Resource> vres;
  size_t hint = 0;

  std::condition_variable cv;
  std::mutex mtx;
  size_t available_cnt;

  public:

  Pool(std::initializer_list<T> l): available_cnt(l.size()) {
    vres.reserve(l.size());
    for (T t: l) {
      vres.emplace_back(std::move(t));
    }
std::cout << "Pool has size " << vres.size() << std::endl;
  }

  ~Pool() {
    for ( auto & res: vres ) {
      if ( ! res.available ) {
        std::cerr << "WARNING Pool::~Pool resources are still in use\n";
      }
    }
  }

  Borrowed borrow() {
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(mtx);
    cv.wait(lk, [&](){return available_cnt > 0;});
    if ( vres[hint].available ) {
      // quick path, if hint points to an available resource
std::cout << "hint good" << std::endl;
      vres[hint].available = false;
      --available_cnt;
      Borrowed b(*this, hint, vres[hint].val);
      if ( hint + 1 < vres.size() ) ++hint;
      return b; // <--- gcc seems to hang here
    } else {
      // full scan to find the available resource
std::cout << "hint bad" << std::endl;
      for ( hint = 0; hint < vres.size(); ++hint ) {
        if ( vres[hint].available ) {
          vres[hint].available = false;
          --available_cnt;
          return Borrowed(*this, hint, vres[hint].val);
        }
      }
    }
    throw std::runtime_error("Pool::borrow() no resource is available - internal logic error");
  }

  void collect(Borrowed & b) {
    if ( &(b.pool) != this ) 
      throw std::runtime_error("Pool::collect() trying to collect resource owned by another pool!");
    if ( b.val ) {
      b.val = nullptr;
      {
        std::scoped_lock<std::mutex> lk(mtx);
        hint = b.id;
        vres[hint].available = true;
        ++available_cnt;
      }
      cv.notify_one();
    }
  }
};

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

#include <thread>
#include <chrono>

int main() {
  Pool<std::string> pool{"hello","world"};

  std::vector<std::thread> vt;
  for (int i = 10; i > 0; --i) {
    vt.emplace_back( [&pool, i]()
      { 
        auto res = pool.borrow();
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(i*300));
        std::cout << res.get() << std::endl;
      }
    );
  }

  for (auto & t: vt) t.join();

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I guess, it's not a compiler difference here, not effectively. You likely observe a race condition. Try to enhance your debugging here with dedicated logs before each lock (thread id/lock function f.i.) and output the condition variable's state too. Spurious wake ups might be an issue here too.

Comment: @Secundi Yeah, that's what I spent the last few hours doing. I even run the working executable (compiled with clang) through valgrind helgrind, which did not detect any multithreading issue. It seems that gcc does not return from the `Pool::borrow` function and does not release the lock on the mutex, but I am really confused by why is that.

Comment: Ok, I still did not find the core issue but a few things noticed: you're locking within a destructor. For various reasons, I'd recommend to redesign that if possible. since that can lead to various possibly hard to find further issues (exception handling,...). Also try to make your conditional lock robust against spurious wake ups! With MSVC, I observe a direct system exception within the collect() method (locking) - A strong hint for a race condition here.

Comment: @Secundi avoiding the lock in the destructor is as easy as calling `res.release();` at the end of the thread lambda function, but it makes no difference. Why are you saying that the lock is not robust against spurious wakes? It should be as I test the number of available resources on the call to wait.

Comment: See my answer, I think I found your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Locking destructor coupled with missed NRVO caused the issue (credits to Secundi for pointing this out in the comments).

If the compiler skips NRVO, the few lines below if will call the destructor of `b`. The destructor tries to acquire the mutex before this gets released by the `unique_lock`, resulting in a deadlock.

```
Borrowed b(*this, hint, vres[hint].val);
if ( hint + 1 < vres.size() ) ++hint;
return b; // <--- gcc seems to hang here
```

It is of crucial importance here to avoid destroying `b`. In fact, even if manually releasing the `unique_lock` before returning will avoid the deadlock, the destructor of `b` will mark the pooled resource as available, while this is just being borrowed out, making the code wrong.

A possible fix consists in replacing the lines above with:

```
const auto tmp = hint;
if ( hint + 1 < vres.size() ) ++hint;
return Borrowed(*this, tmp, vres[tmp].val);
```

Another possibility (which does not exclude the former) is to delete the (evil) copy ctor of `Borrowed` and only provide a move ctor:

```
Borrowed(const Borrowed &) = delete;
Borrowed(Borrowed && b): pool(b.pool), id(b.id), val(b.val) { b.val = nullptr; }
```

Comment: Yeah, I supposed that unlock to be semantically wrong there. Move semantics should be the robust way to go here since it emphasizes what you really want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

You're running into undefined behavior since you effectively relock an already acquired lock. With MSVC I obtained a helpful callstack to distinguish this. Here is a working fixed example (I suppose, works now for me, see the changes within the borrow() method, might be further re-designed since locking inside a destructor might be questioned):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>

template <typename T>
class Pool {
  ///////////////////////////
  class Borrowed {
    friend class Pool<T>;
    Pool<T>& pool;
    const size_t id;
    T * val;

  public:
    Borrowed(Pool & p, size_t i, T& v) : pool(p), id(i), val(&v) {}
    ~Borrowed() { release(); }

    T& get() const {
      if (!val) throw std::runtime_error("Borrowed::get() this resource was collected back by the pool");
      return *val;
    }

    void release() { pool.collect(*this); }
  };
  ///////////////////////////    
  struct Resource {
    T val;
    bool available = true;
    Resource(T v) : val(std::move(v)) {}
  };
  ///////////////////////////

  std::vector<Resource> vres;
  size_t hint = 0;

  std::condition_variable cv;
  std::mutex mtx;
  size_t available_cnt;

public:

  Pool(std::initializer_list<T> l) : available_cnt(l.size()) {
    vres.reserve(l.size());
    for (T t : l) {
      vres.emplace_back(std::move(t));
    }
    std::cout << "Pool has size " << vres.size() << std::endl;
  }

  ~Pool() {
    for (auto & res : vres) {
      if (!res.available) {
        std::cerr << "WARNING Pool::~Pool resources are still in use\n";
      }
    }
  }

  Borrowed borrow() {
    
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(mtx);
    while (available_cnt == 0) cv.wait(lk);

    if (vres[hint].available) {
      // quick path, if hint points to an available resource
      std::cout << "hint good" << std::endl;
      vres[hint].available = false;
      --available_cnt;
      Borrowed b(*this, hint, vres[hint].val);
      if (hint + 1 < vres.size()) ++hint;
      lk.unlock();
      return b; // <--- gcc seems to hang here
    }
    else {
      // full scan to find the available resource
      std::cout << "hint bad" << std::endl;
      for (hint = 0; hint < vres.size(); ++hint) {
        if (vres[hint].available) {
          vres[hint].available = false;
          --available_cnt;
          lk.unlock();
          return Borrowed(*this, hint, vres[hint].val);
        }
      }
    }
    throw std::runtime_error("Pool::borrow() no resource is available - internal logic error");
  }

  void collect(Borrowed & b) {
    if (&(b.pool) != this)
      throw std::runtime_error("Pool::collect() trying to collect resource owned by another pool!");
    if (b.val) {
      b.val = nullptr;
      {
        std::scoped_lock<std::mutex> lk(mtx);
        hint = b.id;
        vres[hint].available = true;
        ++available_cnt;
        cv.notify_one();
      }
    }
  }
};

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

#include <thread>
#include <chrono>



////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
int main()
{
  try
  {
    Pool<std::string> pool{ "hello","world" };

    std::vector<std::thread> vt;
    for (int i = 10; i > 0; --i) {
      vt.emplace_back([&pool, i]()
        {
          auto res = pool.borrow();
          std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(i * 300));
          std::cout << res.get() << std::endl;
        }
      );
    }

    for (auto & t : vt) t.join();

    return 0;
  }
  catch(const std::exception& e)
  {
    std::cout << "exception occurred: " << e.what();
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Where do I effectively relock an already acquired lock?

Comment: Why did you add `lk.unlock();`? The unique_lock destructor is unlocking the mutex anyway, no?

Comment: You have a possible NRVO-issue at least, see return b. Depends on the compiler here what happens currently

Comment: @DarioP due to missed NRVO, the destructor of Borrowed can happen before the unique_lock gets destroyed

Comment: PS: The unlock should be avoided if possible, I solely used it here to emphasize the underlying issue.

Comment: PS2: Works with gcc as well now